# Create Folder in Internal storage

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Can i create a folder into the root of internal storage (ex. on my gs4 /storage/emulated/0/MY_FOLDER).
in this pah are present many folder of other app, like viber,audijo whatsapp so i think that it's possible.

Thank you

the code

```
File folder = new File( Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/storage/emulated/0/MyFolder");
    folder.mkdir();
```

Comment: did you try to read the documentation?
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Comment: Did you even try to search it??

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It is possible to create a folder in Internal Storage directory as below:

```
 Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/storage/emulated/0/MyFolder"
```

Comment: It return this path: /data/myFolder

Comment: Yes. Please tell me ur desired path... i will update my code accordingly.

Comment: ok. Thank you. So i would like to have this path:storage/emulated/0/MyFolder. I have found this folder when i run android "file manager" and i choose device storage.

Comment: I have edited my answer....Please check and let me know you are getting desired path or not

Comment: @user2516977 do u find the solution??

Comment: it doesen't create. Now I add my code in my question.

Comment: Now check and let me know if any issue. I have updated my answer

Comment: sorry, it doesn't work.

Comment: It doesnt work means what? Is there any error??

Comment: no error. Do not create the folder.

Comment: What is the path are you checking. Open `DDMS Perspective in Eclipse-> File Explorer ->data -> /storage/emulated/0/MyFolder`. The folder should be created

Comment: I have checked on DDMS. Non folder has been created. I don't know why

Comment: Can u place ur code... so that i will check and let u know

Comment: The code that i use for create the folder is written in my question. I have tried also this But i have the sema result:
'File asd = new File( Environment.getRootDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/storage/emulated/0/folder");'

Answer (score 2):

You can create Folder this way.

```
    public  String  path = Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString()+ "/YourDirectoryName";
    File mFolder = new File(path);
                if (!mFolder.exists()) {
                    mFolder.mkdir();
                }
```

Comment: i need internal storage

Comment: i have already try it, but the folder is not created

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in your activity:

```
String filename = "filename";
String fileContents = "Text in file.";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(fileContents.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

Comment: it return this path: data/data/MyPackage/files/MyFolder.

Comment: That is correct. That is the path where files private to your application will be saved on the internal storage.